# jQuery Mobile - Maintain scroll position on device orientation change?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-events

I'm using `jQuery-mobile` to display a list of data. The list can get fairly tall, say ~3000px. The problem I'm seeing on my `Samsung G S5` is when I rotate the phone, the listview loses it's scroll position and gets positioned at the top.

I've tried to do the following but couldn't get it to work:

```
// This block is to handle the device rotating when viewing the list
    $(window).on('scrollstop', function() {
        if ($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == 'pageBeingViewed') {
            self.currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        }            
    });
    $(window).on("orientationchange", function (event) {
        if ($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == 'pageBeingViewed') {
            console.log('Scroll Pos:'+self.currentScroll);
            $(window).scrollTop(self.currentScroll);  // also tried using the jQM silent scroll method here as well.  No luck.       
        }           
    });
```

Logically, this should work. It captures the scroll position on the fly, so then when you rotate the device, it should reposition it back to where it was. But I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not working. Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Are you using responsive grids (or other media queries)? If so, chances are your page is taller in portrait mode, and scroll positions will not be directly applicable from one mode to the other.

Comment: It's just the default jQM listview plugin.  There are no additional complexities here. It's just trying to display a simple list.

As for the scroll position being different, it's just got to be close.  I can tweak the calculations if anyone has a workaround, I'm not worried about that.

Comment: Also, for the record I have opened an issue with the jQM team: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7784.  This is really an internal bug and should be fixed as such, but in the interim I was hoping we could figure out a work around.

Comment: You should scroll div containing listview. If it's wrapped in `ui-content` then scroll that div not window. Or better way is using `$.mobile.silentScroll(position)` this special function doesn't trigger scroll event.

Comment: changing orientation is causing page to scroll, which changes last scroll position.

Comment: @Omar I tried to use the silent scroll function, but it didn't work as well.  It seems to be an internal bug as far as I can tell.  It's inconsistent across browsers.  It works fine in chrome, but fails in the android webview phonegap uses.  Weird...

Answer (score -1):

Check You `divs` on `firebug` and make sure which is the element that has the scrollbar. sometimes it happens that the `body`, `page` and `ui-content` are set to `100%` height and so the scroll bar ends up in the `ui-content` div. If that is the case, you can solve it by directly accessing `scrollTop()` of the div which has the scrollbar.